# Getting ng-content components using @ViewChild?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've created a card with a template that uses `ng-content` slots like this:

```
  <ng-content select="card-header"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-body"></ng-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
```

And within the `CardComponent` I'm trying to grab the `CardHeaderComponent` reference using `@ViewChild` like this:

```
  @ViewChild(CardHeaderComponent)
  header: CardHeaderComponent;
```

I does not look like it is succeeding though, per the log statement in `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
    console.log(this.header);
```

[This is the Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhewvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard.component.ts).

Thoughts?

Comment: I just went to your Stackblitz demo and I dont think the app is hooked up correctly. Even if I attempt to console.log in the AppModule, or any module for that matter, there is nothing in the console. So probably need to resolve that first.

Comment: @NicholasPorter thanks for the heads up.  I refreshed the link and pasted in the new one.  Does it work now?

Comment: yes working now, taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `@ViewChild` use `@ContentChildren` like this:

```
@ContentChildren(CardHeaderComponent) header: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Comment: @ole if you wouldn't mind accepting my answer that would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: that's how I'm used to using `ViewChild` also.  Unfortunately I can't do that in this case because the `card-header` is supposed to be optional.  So I'm hoping theres a way to grab it if the design time user of the component decides to add the header ...

Comment: If it is optional you can try using `ngIf` to conditionally load the header based on some variable.

Comment: Well it's just that in this case the design time user needs to be able to include it within `card` if they choose to do so and they can also add custom content within the header ... So in other words the component has to ship the way it is and then users are supposed to be able to slot in content when they are using the component.  I could change the design, but I'm hoping there's a way to get the component slotted using the design as is, because this is a fairly standard way to design cards with slots and also very low maintanence.

Comment: @NicholasPorts it looks like we can use `@ContentChildren`.  Stackblitz demo here.  Do you want to update your answer with that and I can accept?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the answer and accepted.  Thanks again for all the feedback.

Comment: Cool glad you found a better alternative.